# RStudio - strange behavior of read.csv (transformed colnames)

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I have a csv xxx.csv I read on RStudio with `data<-read.csv(file="xxx.csv",header=TRUE)`.

My problem is that when I retrieve the column names of my data whith `colnames(data)`,all "-" are replaced by "."

For example in my csv file I have a column name that is "AER-XY", but in R it is changed in "AER.XY".

Can I resolve that or is the format of my names the problem?

Comment: Use `check.names=FALSE`.

Comment: you could try `check.names=FALSE` as parameter for read.csv

Comment: Works well, thanks !